# set header on rsocket messages with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rsocket

so I've started playing with rsocket and spring boot 2.2 to see if I can use it in my projects, but I'm facing a bit of troubles.

Normally, with spring messaging I define a listener method like the following:

```
@MessageMapping("addGeolocation")
public Mono<Boolean> addGeolocation(@Header("metadata") MmeMetadata metadata, @Payload String geolocation) { ... }
```

My understanding is that with rsocket I should be able to use the same logic, but when I'm defining the client I couldn't find an easy way to set message headers.

Currently I'm stuck with this:

```
boolean outcome = rSocketRequester.route("addGeolocation").metadata(...?).data(geolocationWKT).block();
```

is the metadata a replacement for headers? that method signature seems a little too generic to be used like headers. If I put an Map in it will spring be able to decode headers out of it?

Thank you,
Fernando

Comment: The more I dig into this, the more awkward it gets. In my opinion RSocket should be integrated with spring webflow, not with spring messaging. Things like RabbitMQ and ActiveMQ have nothing in common with rsocket...

Comment: would be nice to see a reproducer from github or gitlab ?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this question: [RSocket Metadata - custom object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66501888/rsocket-metadata-custom-object).
I used it as a starting point for my solution.

The term 'header' actually means some custom metadata. So, in order to get the correct value you need to configure metadataExtractorRegistry. For Spring Boot do it this way (code in kotlin):

```
val CUSTOM_MIMETYPE = MimeType.valueOf("<some custom mime type>")
val CUSTOM_HEADER = "<the name of a header>"
...
@Bean
fun rSocketStrategiesCustomizer(): RSocketStrategiesCustomizer {
        return RSocketStrategiesCustomizer { strategies: RSocketStrategies.Builder ->
            strategies.metadataExtractorRegistry {
                it.metadataToExtract(CUSTOM_MIMETYPE, String::class.java, CUSTOM_HEADER)
            }
        }
    }
```

The type of the data object can be any, not necessarily a String. There is default String endcoder/decoder, so I didn't provide one in the code. For your own type you can provide one of existing encoders/decoders (Json for example) or create your own:

```
@Bean
fun rSocketStrategiesCustomizer(): RSocketStrategiesCustomizer {
        return RSocketStrategiesCustomizer { strategies: RSocketStrategies.Builder ->
            strategies.metadataExtractorRegistry {
                it.metadataToExtract(CUSTOM_MIMETYPE, YourType::class.java, CUSTOM_HEADER)
            }.decoder(Jackson2JsonDecoder())
             .encoder(Jackson2JsonEncoder())
        }
    }
```

After you've configured registry as above, use the header name defined in the registry in your controller:

```
@MessageMapping("addGeolocation")
public Mono<Boolean> addGeolocation(@Header(CUSTOM_HEADER) String metadata, @Payload String geolocation) { ... }
```

And in order to send that header, use next code:

```
boolean outcome = rSocketRequester.route("addGeolocation")
.metadata("value", CUSTOM_MIMETYPE)
.data(geolocationWKT)
.block();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a bag of name-value pairs (i.e. headers), RSocket uses metadata which can be in any format (i.e. MIME type) and it can be [composite metadata](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket/blob/master/Extensions/CompositeMetadata.md) with multiple types of metadata each formatted differently. So you can have one section with routing metadata, another with security, yet another with tracing, and so on.

To achieve something similar to headers, you can send name-value pairs as JSON-formatted metadata. Now on the server side, you'll need to provide a hint to Spring for how to extract a Map (of headers) from the metadata of incoming requests. To do that you can configure a `MetadataExtractor` and that's described in [this section](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket/blob/master/Extensions/CompositeMetadata.md) of the docs. Once that's configured, the extracted Map becomes the headers of the message and can be accessed from `@MessageMapping` methods as usual (via `MessageHeaders`, `@Header`, etc).

Comment: The answer may be in there somewhere, but I for one am not able to figure it out. A code sample showing what you have to do on the client side to pass any kind of value into a parameter that has a '@Header' annotation would be much more helpful than a link to the specification of low-level RSocket protocol details.

Comment: Since I couldn't figure out how to pass some extra data as a 'header', I just added this data directly to the 'payload' instead. That works I guess but it is a bit unsatisfactory and seems like a 'ugly hack'.